# Como arreglar las URL de mi pagina wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Se que entrando al area de ajustes se puede estructurar las URL pero no se por que no me deja arreglarlo, hice la configuracion de la forma correcta, revise los slug de las paginas y los productos pero al entrar en la pagina desde otros navegadores siguen apareciendo URL'S NO amigables
[www.xiaomimportperu.com](http://www.xiaomimportperu.com)

Comment: Por favor se más descriptivo con tu problema. ¿Por que dices que no te deja arreglarlo? ¿Que errores te aparecen? ¿A que páginas con urls no amigables te refieres?

Comment: Ahora mismo, entro a tu página, reviso productos, y veo todo correcto

Comment: Entre desde Chrome y Edge, ningun problema

Comment: A mi también me funciona bien desde firefox

Comment: Funciona bien, creo que el problema no es del sitio, si no que tu navegador guardo la cache y por ende sigues viendo los enlaces anteriores, prueba desde incognito o a eliminar el cache, el problema debería estar solucionado